# How to comment a line of a XAML file in C# /WPF with System.XAML defining value from multiple Inputs lines

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Sequence>
 <Inputs>
 <Input>readOF</Input>
 <Input>readReference</Input>
 </Inputs>
 </Steps>
 </Sequence>
```

I need to comment and uncomment the 4th line of this XAML file using System.XML properties:
Desired output:

```
<!--<Input>readOF</Input>-->
```

This is my node :

```
// Get the target node using XPath
 System.Xml.XmlNode elementToComment = xDocument.SelectSingleNode("//Sequence/Inputs/Input");
```

My code  works only if have one only input witch I can define my element with out any problem

but when I  have more than one input and trying to add its value to my Node selection like this nothing works  :

```
  System.Xml.XmlNode elementToComment = xDocument.SelectSingleNode("//Sequence/Inputs/Input/ReadOF");
```

so my question is how can I add node value to my code .

here is my code :

```
// Find the proper path to the XML file
          String xmlFilePath = "path\\xmfile.xml";

           // Create an XmlDocument
           System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

           // Load the XML file in to the document
           xmlDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);

           // Get the target node using XPath
           System.Xml.XmlNode elementToComment = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/Sequence/Inputs/Input");

           // Get the XML content of the target node
           String commentContents = elementToComment.OuterXml;

           // Create a new comment node
           // Its contents are the XML content of target node
           System.Xml.XmlComment commentNode = xmlDocument.CreateComment(commentContents);

           // Get a reference to the parent of the target node
           System.Xml.XmlNode parentNode = elementToComment.ParentNode;

           // Replace the target node with the comment
           parentNode.ReplaceChild(commentNode, elementToComment);

           xmlDocument.Save(xmlFilePath);
           MessageBox.Show("ok");
```

Sorry for my English , Thank you for any attention .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to select the parent node, iterate through it's children, and replace the one that has InnerText == "readOF".
Like this:

```
    System.Xml.XmlNode inputs = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/Sequence/Inputs");
    foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode child in inputs.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (child.InnerText == "readOF")
        {
            String commentContents = child.OuterXml;
            System.Xml.XmlComment commentNode = xmlDocument.CreateComment(commentContents);
            inputs.RemoveChild(child);
            inputs.PrependChild(commentNode);               
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this is work finally , but this code remote  the input that I comment it  before  the rest inputs . Is there a way to comment my input with same order line and with out  moving  it :) . Thank you

Comment: Yes, use inputs.ReplaceChild(commentNode, child), like in your code. (for some reason it didn't work for me earlier in dotnetfiddle, but it should work)

Comment: Thank you this is work perfectly   :)                        `child.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(commentNode, child);`

Answer (score 1):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement input = doc.Descendants("Input").Where(x => (string)x == "readOF").FirstOrDefault();

            input.ReplaceWith("<!--<Input>readOF</Input>-->");

            doc.Save(FILENAME);

       }


    }


}
```